# how to listen to keyboard search button in searchView

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, searchview

I have a SearchView. When the user clicks on the **keyboard** search button, I need to make a server call. What does the code for the listener look like? I am thinking I have to use OnClickListener. But the internal code for knowing it's the search button, I am not sure how to determine that.

Comment: It sends the KeyEvent#KEYCODE_SEARCH key so you would look for that with an onKeyEventListener or activity's dispatchKeyEvent

Comment: @DeeV The docs say that onKeyEventListener is for hardware key. Why would it specifically say hardware if it equally applies to the soft keyboard? In any case, I will try it since you say it's the answer.

Comment: @DeeV I already tried onEditorActionListener before asking the question. But the SearchView does not recognize it.

Comment: show some code of your search view

Comment: @QadirHussain do you even understand the question? Your catch-all comment does not belong here.

Comment: There's an interesting workaround here: [SearchView listen for IME actions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33385262/383414)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I have done like this

the `onQueryTextSubmit` is the method you are looking for.

set `setOnQueryTextListener` on your search view.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_city);
    searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search View Hint");

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            //Log.e("onQueryTextChange", "called");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {


            // Do your task here

            return false;
        }

    });

    return true;
}
```

hope this help

Comment: Yay! Ok you beat me to the response. I will up vote!

Answer (score 2):

This is the kotlin version:

```
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

            override fun onQueryTextChange(s: String): Boolean {
                // make a server call
                return true
            }

            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(s: String): Boolean {
                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, YourSearchableActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, s)
                intent.putExtra(CUSTOM_MESSAGE, "you can also add custom message when submitting the search action")
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)
                startActivity(intent)
                return true
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you can go for the Android best answer not Kotlin

```
        binding.edtSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                // Your piece of code on keyboard search click
                if (AppValidator.isValid(SearchEventsActivity.this, binding.edtSearch, "Please enter your search keyword.")) {
                    searchKeyword = binding.edtSearch.getText().toString().trim();
                    //Search Events categories
                    callSearchEventsApi();
                }

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Make sure you have added following line in your EditText

```
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
```

Just like following:-

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtSearch"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text_color_light"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:hint="@string/search"/>
```

I hope this will help you to solve your issue.!!!!

Answer (score 0):

SearchView method

> setOnQueryTextLister

will do your work as below shown.

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                showSnackBar(query.toString());
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Here searchView is object of SearchView.