# Kotlin: how to get searchView submit

Tags: android, kotlin, submit, searchview

I have a [SearchView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView):

```xml
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

I want to add a custom action when the submit button is pressed.

This is what I have so far:

```kotlin
searchBar.setOnSearchClickListener {
  //do some stuff
}
```

All the information I found is old and not in kotlin.

How can I get trigger an action when the search icon on the keyboard is tapped?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)

    val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_city)
    searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search View Hint")

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : OnQueryTextListener {

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            // task HERE
            return false
        }

    })

    return true
}
```

Response link: [Listen to keyboard event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306717/how-to-listen-to-keyboard-search-button-in-searchview)