# How to know when keyboard will hide using SearchView in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview

I want to do something after search but for this I must be notified of hiding the keyboard. Is there an action for SearchView like:

```
override fun onKeyboardHide() {
   /...
}
```

?

Comment: Here you can see how to create a listener on keyboard : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216749/soft-keyboard-open-and-close-listener-in-an-activity-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of a listener doing exactly this.
But you can archiv something like that by listening for Input of the search confirmation and additionally listen to the onBackPress Event of your context / activity.
For checking the search event Look Here:
[how to listen to keyboard search button in searchView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306717/how-to-listen-to-keyboard-search-button-in-searchview)